# How to make a variable globally accessible across multiple templates

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

In my phoenix app, I am trying to load a bunch of data and make them accessible to my root template (across all pages). To my knowledge, this is done via assigns, but I don't know where to load it.

I think something like

```
use App.LiveView
use App.News

assign(socket, news: News.all)
```

should work, but I don't know where to put this code, so the socket would be available. Coming from Express.js, I'm looking to do something like:

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  // Load news into global variable
  // ...
  next()
})
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: have you tried using a plug to inject the data your require into assings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-LiveView Phoenix equivalent of Express' `router.use` would be [`Router.plug/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#plug/2). You could just add a plug in a [pipeline](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#module-pipelines-and-plugs).

A plug could either be defined as a module or a simple function.

Here is a minimal example:

```elixir
  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    # ...
    plug :my_plug  # <= add your plug
  end

  def my_plug(conn, _opts) do
    Plug.Conn.assign(conn, :news, News.all())
  end
```

But this wouldn't work with LiveView, which doesn't have access to plug assigns. Since LiveView 0.17, you can use a [mount hook](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/security-model.html#mounting-considerations) to achieve this. You need to add an `on_mount/1` to your `AppWeb.live_view/0`.

```elixir
def live_view do
  quote do
    use Phoenix.LiveView,
      layout: {AppWeb.LayoutView, "live.html"}

    on_mount AppWeb.NewsLiveFetcher  # <= add this
    unquote(view_helpers())
  end
end
```

And implement `AppWeb.NewsLiveFetcher` something like:

```elixir
defmodule AppWeb.NewsLiveFetcher do
  import Phoenix.LiveView

  def on_mount(:default, _params, _session, socket) do
    socket = assign_new(socket, :news, &News.all/0)
    {:cont, socket}
  end
end
```

Comment: Beware of overwriting `on_mount/4` in the implementation using `live_view/0`.